# Open Source Forum for wordpress similar to stackexchange or stackoverflow

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, forum

I have to add forum feature in my wordpress blog.I see bbpress but would like to add forum similar to stackexchange or stackoverflow. 
Please let me know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Plugins:**

- [Question and Answer Forum Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/question-and-answer-forum/)
- [WP-Answers Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-answers/)

**Themes:**

- [AskIt](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/askit/)
- [Instant Q&A](http://themeforest.net/item/instant-qa/92361)

Comment: Do they have point system? I don't want to change existing blog. I would like to add forum feature.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other forum plugins that do this. I believe the options I suggested can be made to have a point system. One way you could use these without altering your existing blog much would be to make it a multi_site install and put the q&a on a sub domain.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my theme that has the major features of SO/SE like user points, comment voting up and down: http://wpverse.com/civicstack

It's a light/mini version that people can expand on.

Answer (score 1):

I have this plugin if you are interested.

http://www.sabaidiscuss.com/

> SabaiDiscuss is a premium questions and answers plugin for WordPress. The plugin features the ability for users to ask and answer questions similar to Stack Overflow or Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Do you have it installed? Or you are the author?

Comment: Yes, I'm the author. You can test the [demo](http://demo.sabaidiscuss.com/) if you like.

Comment: Ok, interesting plugin. No prob with the demo, there's a nice green button to click when we visit the page :) - Please, take note of this FAQ item: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion