# Forum for wordpress - Super confused!

Tags: plugin-recommendation, forum

I want to start a website/blog on wordpress and am also thinking about integrating a forum in it. Now, I have been reading reviews about forums for wordpress like BB press, Simple Forum, Mingle, etc. Some say bbpress doesnt have many features. Others say Simple forum cant be customized. I a novice. I dont know php coding and all. I can learn though.

I want to install a forum in my wordpress website that doesnt really need coding and all. Something that has many features, is highly customizable and goes well with the theme of my wordpress website. If I could have a Q/A forum like stackexchange, that would be so awesome!

I want the forum to be incorporated in my website only so that users dont have to login to two different websites.

Someone please clear my doubts and suggest which way to go!? Thanks :))

edit- can someone please help me out in here? : /

Comment: "*It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*"

Comment: @Chip - I just want to know which is the most preferred forum plugin that can be incorporated with wordpress and is customizable :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already asked this question before about a forum like StackExchange for Wordpress and the answers might be of some help to you.

[Open Source Forum for wordpress similar to stackexchange or stackoverflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/open-source-forum-for-wordpress-similar-to-stackexchange-or-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a more robust plugin that include the features of a standalone solution, I would recommend either [SimplePress](http://simple-press.com/features/) or [Mingle](http://cartpauj.icomnow.com/projects/mingle-forum-plugin/).  It really comes down to your preference and what 'exact' features you're looking to implement without any coding.

Both solutions are skinnable to match to your existing installation and will offer the easiest to use out of the box experience for a non-coder.